# Android Studio: Background task running indefinitely

Tags: android, android-studio

After updating the Android SDK, I started Android Studio. Now its showing background task continuously running with message

> Updating indices: Scanning files to index.

In this mode, it is nearly hanged and I can not work on it. Not able to find a way to stop background task. A restart of Android Studio didn't work either.

Comment: Try using the `Invalidate Caches / Restart` option - it can be found in the `File` menu.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, this didn't work. Has OP figured it out yet?

Comment: Updating client works!

Comment: It would be nice if OP could select an answer that worked for him! Invalidating the Caches fixed the  problem for me.

Comment: This might be fixed in Android Studio 2.2. See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=211761

Answer (score 86, accepted):

I've find out that I should use the solution of @free3dom which is the `Invalidate Caches / Restart option` in the File menu.

I have to do this every time I change some project file by switching branches in GIT.

And yes, Android Studio really sucks and is full of bugs...

Comment: I recently faced the issue on AS 3.1.2 and your answer saved me. AS is sucks these days :(

Comment: Version 2 was better. Sometimes on version 3 logcat does not show until three or four restarts of android emulator... :(

Comment: @FonzTech I always do `adb kill-server` and `adb devices` on a terminal window. This makes sure I don't have to restart emulator. It might help you.

Comment: I also faced this in 3.1.4. Google should release stable issues.

Comment: I just faced that same issue with Android Studio 4.1  The Invalidate Caches / Restart option in the File menu solution still works.

Answer (score 30):

Unplug all the phones and plug them again, it gets working. It is related to adb as stated here : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=172387 and a known bug that is to be fixed in the future

Comment: well the bug isn't fixed yet

Comment: Thanks Buddy. This unblocked me :)

Comment: 2019 reporting in - issue is still open. Had the same indexing situation when opening  existing project in AS 3.5.1 (btw build Help -> About copy function is not working also). Had to shut down emulator for it to start indexing

Answer (score 3):

The indexing is triggered through inotify on Linux.
There is a limit to how many directories a single user can set watches on. If your project is large, then this limit may be exceeded, and Android Studio falls back to recursive scanning mode, which is very slow.

To fix this, add this line to `/etc/sysctl.conf file`:

```
# Increase the limit for Android Studio
`fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 500000`
```

Then run `sudo sysctl -p`.

Answer (score 1):

Stopping and closing the emulators that I had running solved this issue for me on the latest version of Android Studio.

Comment: Even today, your answer saved me :D

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was a module circular dependency problem. It wouldn't show until I removed all the changes into all `build.gradle` files, then reopen it and apply the stash.

It works :)

Answer (score 0):

I've this problem recently and in my case I'm using a linux 64bit SO and my android studio was in a ntfs disk. Since ntfs doesn't support executable permition the file fsnotifier64 was unable to execute and android-studio fallback into a compatibility mode that is much slower. The solution was copy the android-studio folder into my home folder that was ext4 and that way i was able to set permitions.

Comment: This can't be the solution, as I've got the same issue on Windows

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this issue for almost one hour, and after that found that this is the adb connection issue, you can disconnect your device once and stops all the working adb processes. This issue may get resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also facing this issue, I've tried almost all the methods mentioned in this post, but none of them worked. The only solution that worked for me is to upgrade Android Studio to 3.5(which is still a test version at the time of writing this answer).

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me after updating the Android Gradle plugin version from (3.5.3)
to (3.6.2)  and Gradle version from (5.4.1) to (5.6.4)
it solved after downgrading the plugin again
to change Android Gradle plugin version and Gradle version:
File > Project Structure > Project 
[image: File > Project Structure]

[image: Change it due to android studio reference]

[image: Update Gradle Reference]

reference: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html

Answer (score 0):

I just cleared the entire cache of my device , and it look it worked for me .
As I am on a mac so , these are the steps I followed :

1. Open finder
2. Use the shortcut shift+cmd+G
3. Paste this `/Users/*[replace with your mac profile name]/Library/Caches`
4. cmd+A to select all
5. cmd+delete to move to trash

Answer (score -1):

This was happening in my project every time I added a new Activity.
So I included my R file in that class and it stopped.

> eg: import com.domain.appname.R;

This fixed the problem.