# Android-Studio: "Gradle is running. Proceed with Project closing?"

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new and unexperienced to developing Android (Ubuntu 14.04, Android Studio 1.4). I am just trying to solve multiple errors to get my code build, and when I do I get a popup saying

```
Gradle is running. Proceed with Project closing?
```

Searching this exact string on google returns 6 hits (most of them from the android developer bugtracking system). Here is a screenshot:

[image]

I would like to know what this message means. Will it close the Project when I click 'Yes' (which is not what I want)? What button should I click here?

Answer (score 3):

This message means the gradle is running tasks in background.
Sometimes you click 'Yes' stops the tasks.
I think this link can be useful for you

[Android Studio: Background task running indefinitely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17834821/android-studio-background-task-running-indefinitely)

[How to stop Gradle task execution in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21184794/how-to-stop-gradle-task-execution-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

In that situation you can safely click 'Yes' as it does not clode the Project. But you can go on working...

P.S. No idea what the text means!

Comment: have the same issue. just a popup that means nothing and any button click never closes project. Android studio 1.3.1