# Android studio process Scanning files to index looping forever

Tags: android, android-studio

Today when I started Android Studio it got stuck with "Scanning files to index..." in the background process and it never finishes. I can open the background processes display and see it looping over the same directories. Yesterday it was working fine and there were no issues with my project.

I tried:

- clearing caches and restart;
- I tried deleting the system caches directory in `C:\Users\xxx\.AndroidStudio3.5\system\caches` and restarting;
- Disconnected all devices, no AVDs running;
- reinstalled the Android Studio (3.5.2 built 31-Oct-2019), I already had the latest, but WTH!
- rebooted windows!

Is there a way to kill this process. I cannot do builds or debug.

I looked at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17834821/android-studio-background-task-running-indefinitely) but it is old and nothing suggested helped.

Comment: 4 years later and this still happens. I moved my project folder to a different computer with Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 4 installed and working with other projects, but on attempting to load old projects it's stuck at "Scanning files to index."

Comment: Worse, even attempting to open the old project results in corrupting the *new* one, throwing "Cannot access `androidx.savedstate.SavedStateRegistryOwner` which is a supertype of `com.myfiles.myapp.MainActivity`. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Out of desperation I re-installed Android Studio, but first uninstalled it **removing the user settings** (which I didn't do on the previous uninstall). Threw in a couple of reboots between uninstall and re-install and start up. This seems to have fixed the problem for me!

I have no rational explanation for why, other than something in the user settings directory was causing the problem. I guess if you have a similar problem remember to check the box to delete the user settings when doing the uninstall. It's a shame that this kind of issue doesn't have a work around, it seems to happen intermittently over the years and versions of the Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the similar problems from time to time.
What I found to fix this:

1. Exit another software that is watching the same folders (for me it was Sublime);
2. Exit Android Studio;
3. Wait until "fsnotifier64" process finishes;
4. Start Android Studio.

1st and 2nd items may be probably exchanged.

Answer (score 0):

for me, it happened on Android Studio Hedgehog.

solution was to re-install Android Studio. I did not have to remove my user settings when re-installing.

i took following steps

1. downloaded latest [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio) (which is iguana for now)
2. launch the installer
3. used installer to uninstall current version
4. it was unable to completely remove the folder for the old Android Studio (a file was "in use"), so i restarted my computer, and removed it manually
5. run the AS installer again and installed it
6. run new AS, and issue is resolved

Answer (score -2):

In some case you need good speed internet and good spec too..
Have your pc meet min spec ?

Comment: Could you elaborate on how internet speed/processing power is related to this issue?